# SELECT function to array creating copy of data

Tags: php, sql, arrays, select

Am selecting two pieces of data from a database and placing that data into an array. My code is;

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
$inspectit = array();
$update1 = $_POST['inspect'];
$query1 = "SELECT title, reason FROM daysoff WHERE DATE(start) = '$update1' AND gighold = 1";
$day = mysql_query($query1); 
while($requesting = mysql_fetch_array($day)) {                           
$inspectit = $requesting;
}
$_SESSION['inspect'] = $inspectit; 
 var_dump($inspectit);
 //header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ;
?>
```

When this query is returned and the variable dumped, it displays each piece of data twice like this;

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "Brady" ["title"]=> string(5) "Brady" [1]=> string(7) "hfhjgfj" ["reason"]=> string(7) "hfhjgfj" }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Notice the keys for each duplicated value. One is a number and the other is a column name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`.

As mysql_fetch_array will return id and ascociated title with the id.

Answer (score 2):

[The manual](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) is pretty clear about `mysql_fetch_array`:

```
Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both
```

The doubles are there so you can refer to column either by it's name or it's index.